# Airflow Emr Dag suceeds but cluster not started

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, boto3, airflow, amazon-emr

I am trying to start an AWS emr cluster and submit a step using  `EmrCreateJobFlowOperator` and `EmrAddStepsOperator`, my both steps succed but the cluster is never launch, not even without step

Both of the steps change to succeed status

Here is my code

```
default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=2),
    'start_date': datetime(2019, 1, 1),
    'end_date': datetime(2019, 2, 1),

    'depends_on_past': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5)    
}


step_args = ["spark-submit", '../test.py']

step = [{"Name": "what_you_do-" + time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H:%M"),
            'ActionOnFailure': 'CONTINUE',
            'HadoopJarStep': {
                'Jar': 's3n://elasticmapreduce/libs/script-runner/script-runner.jar',
                'Args': step_args
            }
        }]



JOB_FLOW_OVERRIDES = {
'Instances': {
    'InstanceGroups': [
        {

            'InstanceRole': 'MASTER',
            'InstanceType': 'm4.large',
            'InstanceCount': 1
        },
        {

            'InstanceRole': 'CORE',
            'InstanceType': 'm4.large',
            'InstanceCount': 2,

        }
    ]},
    'Name':'airflow-monthly_agg_custom',

            'BootstrapActions':[{
            'Name': 'Install',
            'ScriptBootstrapAction': {
                'Path': 's3://dep-buck/bootstrap.sh'
            }
        }],
    'Configurations': [
  {
     "Classification": "spark-env",
     "Configurations": [
       {
         "Classification": "export",
         "Properties": {
            "PYSPARK_PYTHON": "/usr/bin/python3"
          }
       }
    ]
  }
]}

dag = DAG('emr_job_flow_automatic_steps_7',
          default_args=default_args,
          schedule_interval="@daily",
          max_active_runs=1,

          #    schedule_interval='*/1 * * * *',

          catchup=True,

          #         dagrun_timeout=timedelta(seconds=10)
          )

cluster_creator = EmrCreateJobFlowOperator(
    task_id='create_job_flow2',
    job_flow_overrides=JOB_FLOW_OVERRIDES,
    aws_conn_id='aws_default',
    emr_conn_id='emr_default',
    dag=dag
)

step_adder = EmrAddStepsOperator(
    task_id='add_steps',
    job_flow_id="{{ task_instance.xcom_pull('create_job_flow2', key='return_value') }}",
    aws_conn_id='aws_default',
    steps=step,
    dag=dag
)

cluster_creator.set_downstream(step_adder)
```

I have tried to search for example or good ocument but there isnt much except function definition on airflow site

for create job flow i have this log repeated several time

[image]

for "add step" i have this in log

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Problem was mainly about the visibilty to users and region, it was starting cluster in the default region so i had to change the properties below

Airflow UI > admin > connection > aws_default > extra

```
{"region_name": "the region i was watching the ec2 console"}
```

Airflow UI > admin > connection > emr_default > extra

```
"VisibleToAllUsers": true,
```